# Optimization problem for competition design

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

My question is about a particular constrained optimization problem, but the problem is motivated by a hypothetical.

**Motivating story:** I'm organizing a competition where $n$ players will play $d$ different single-player games. Overall competition scores will be computed by taking a weighted average over scores in individual games. To make the competition more exciting, I want to assign weights which will make the overall scores close. I have a good idea of how well everybody will do in each game: let's say I expect that the $i$th player will receive a score of $x^{(i)}_k$ in the $k$th game, for $i$ ranging from 1 to $n$ and $k$ ranging from 1 to $d$. What weights should I pick to minimize the sum of all the score
margins?

**Formal problem:** solve
$$ \min_w \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}|w^Tx^{(i)} - w^Tx^{(j)}| $$
subject to $w \geq 0$ and $\sum_{k = 1}^d w_k = 1$.

Comment: What is the actual question? The problem posed above is a linear program after introducing so called epigraph variables to represent the absolute values, so the weights to pick are the values that you get when you solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the technique you're describing. Can you provide more detail about how this becomes a straightforward linear program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up on comment.

Introduce new variables $t_{ij}$ and replace objective with $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} t_{ij}$ and add the constraints $-t_{ij} \leq w^Tx^{(i)} - w^Tx^{(j)} \leq t_{ij}$. With the original constraints, this is a linear program in $(t,w)$ and at optimality $t_{ij}$ will be equal to the absolute value it models (as it otherwise could be reduced).